# Terminating in response to backboard's termination on iPad 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

My app crashes and console shows  message Terminating in response to backboard's termination. I am performing some drawing on high resolution images and then assigning these images back to the UIImageView. First time process goes fine but after second or third call app crashes.

Comment: Check if `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called. My guess is that you use too many ressources.

Comment: @Larme yes i have checked didReceiveMemoryWarning called before crashes. I also tried to free the resources but it didn't fix.